# Open function permission denied only for image

Tags: python, node.js, image, file, permissions

I just create test.py file and write the following code in it.

```
open('test.jpg','wb')
```

And I run it via command Python test.py. Then I got the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
 open('test.jpg','wb')
 PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'img.jpg'
```

But when I change the extension to .txt then its working fine

```
open('test.txt','wb')
```

Both test.jpg and test.txt not exist in the folder

What is the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

`The PermissionError: [Errno 13]` permission denied error occurs when you try to access a file from Python without having the necessary permissions. Usually, there are two solutions to this problem:

- To fix this error, use the `chmod` or `chown` command to change the permissions of the file so that the right user and/or group can access the file. You may have downloaded the file from the Internet, so your PC may try to defend you.
- Close the opened .jpg file on your PC: Python cannot work with the file when you work on it.